# Data partition is now OEM after factory reinstall

Tags: windows-8, dell-inspiron, partition-recovery, oem

My laptop is a Dell inspiron with Windows 8.

HDD is 1 TB, with 3 OEM partitions, + the `C:`. I split it into `C:` and `D:`. Fine.

After a reinstall of Windows 8, using Dell recovery tool, I can't see the `D:` anymore, except in Windows's administration Tools, where I can see it but now as an OEM partition. I can't do any action on it, no delete, no format, nothing...

What can I do to get my 550 GB partition back?

Comment: You would need to use a Linux partition tool.  You need to merge the system partition disk into a single partition, recovery the system, then after Windows 8 is installed partition the system disk into 2 partitions.  I suggest just skipping the recovery tool and finding yourself a Windows 8 image disk.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any linux partition tool that can do the job?

Comment: You had that backed to a separate location right?

Comment: All important data are backed up. I dont' care losing the partition, I just want to free the space and get it back.

Comment: @FrancoisB. - There are numerous tools a good old Google search is helpful in a case like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution: http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-to-delete-oem-partition.html

- cmd
- diskpart
- list disk
- select disk 0
- list partition
- select partition 6
- delete partition override

Data are lost but after that you can format the unallocated space from disk management tool.